# Testing that a value is passed to a method that emits an event, Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a Child component that renders buttons based on an array of objects passed as a prop. The
value passed to the event handler is an object that looks like this: `{ boxes: 1, cookieQty: 4, id: 'chocChip-4', price: 12 }`.

```html
<ul class="list-items">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
        <label :for="item.id" class="label-btn-cookie">{{ title }}</label>
        <button
          :id="item.cookieid"
          v-bind="$attrs"
          type="button"
          :value="item.cookieQty"
          class="cookie-buttons -shadow"
          @click="updateSelection(item)"
        >
          ...
          ...
        </button>

          methods: {
            updateSelection(value) {
              this.$emit("click", value);
             }
           }
```

In the Parent component, the Child looks like this and 'selectboxSize' takes the $event and then dispatches an action.

```html
          <CookieSelect
            :items="chocChipBoxSizesArray"
            :title="chocChip"
            data-cookie="chocolateChip"
            @click="selectBoxSize($event)"
          />

          ....

         selectBoxSize({ cookieQty }) {
          // map the element to an object and use that key to update state
          console.log(event);
          let element = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-cookie");
          this.updateBoxSize({ element, cookieQty });
```

Currently I have a passing test that verifies the button click emits an event. **What I want to do is to test that 'updateSelection' is in fact called with the value passed.**

```
   const mockData = {
     items: chocChipBoxSizesArray,
     title: "ChocolateChip"
   };

   describe("CookieSelect", () => {
     const wrapper = shallowMount(CookieSelect, {
      localVue,
      propsData: { ...mockData }
     });
      it("emits click when clicked", () => {
       const value = { boxes: 1, cookieQty: 4, id: "chocChip-4", price: 12 };
       wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");
       expect(wrapper.emitted("click")).toHaveLength(1); // passes
       expect(wrapper.emitted("click")).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value); // error
     });
...
```

This is the error I get:

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  array
    Received has value: [[{"boxes": 1, "cookieQty": 4, "id": "chocChip-4", "price": 12}]]
```

I've tried spies and mocking a new `MouseEvent()` to no avail.

Comment: *Why* do you want to test that `updateSelection` is called? That's an implementation detail, it sounds like you're already testing the behaviour (that the right value is emitted). When you start spying on bits of the thing you're supposed to be testing, you couple yourself far too closely to its internals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to setup a spy on `updateSelection` in order to verify its calls, and `wrapper.emitted()` doesn't do that for you.

Use [`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to create a spy on the imported component definition before mounting. Also make sure to await the `click` trigger to ensure any side effects from the click have resolved:

```js
import CookieSelect from '@/components/CookieSelect.vue'

it('emits click when called', async () => {
  const updateSelection = jest.spyOn(CookieSelect.methods, 'updateSelection')
  const wrapper = shallowMount(CookieSelect)
  await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')

  const value = /*...*/
  expect(updateSelection).toHaveBeenCalledWith(value)
})
```

Comment: Ok I tried it both async and synchronously, both passed. I guess some downstream side effects could be from dispatching the action and then committing the mutation. As a general rule, one should set up all spies at the top of the file before setting up the shallow mounted wrapper, or maybe in a beforeEach()... your thoughts.

Comment: I think the location of the spy/mock setup depends on the specific implementation to test and personal preference. I personally create the spies/mocks as close to the corresponding assertion (and within the same test) as possible, which makes it easy to reason about the expected outcome. This also allows me to mock certain calls differently in each test if needed.